# Typescript thinks getYear does not exist on type Date

Tags: date, typescript

I'm running tsc inside a webpack project, with `"core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759"` and `"node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"`

Other date properties work fine:

```
private dateToString (date: Date) {
    let month = date.getMonth();
    let day = date.getDate();
    let year = date.getYear() + 1900;

    let dateString = `${month}/${day}/${year}`;
    return dateString;      
}
```

Typescript recognizes `date.getMonth` and `date.getDate` just fine, but on `date.getYear` it gives

`Property 'getYear' does not exist on type 'Date'.`

What definition am I missing?

Comment: Also, you need to increment the month before including it in the string, as `getMonth` returns months 0-11, not 1-12.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! You are correct.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That API is deprecated. Try `getFullYear()` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.
>
> The getYear() method returns the year in the specified date according to local time. Because getYear() does not return full years ("year 2000 problem"), it is no longer used and has been replaced by the getFullYear() method.

Answer (score 5):

Change this line from

```
let year = date.getYear() + 1900;
```

to

```
let year = date.getFullYear();
```